# Can a QtCore Signal be set to the current class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, qt4.8

I am attempting to use a `QtCore.Signal` to send a new instance of a class to the object's parent.
What I am attempting to do is as follows, but fails with:

> `NameError: name 'myClass' is not defined`

```
class myClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    mySignal = QtCore.Signal(myClass)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def create_new_self(self):
        newSelf = myClass(self.parent())
        self.mySignal.emit(newSelf)

class myParentClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myParentClass, self).__init__(parent)
        myNewClass = myClass(self)
        myNewClass.mySignal.connect(self.handle_my_signal)

    @QtCore.Slot(myClass)
    def handle_my_signal(self, newMyClass):
        newMyClass.mySignal.connect(self.handle_my_signal)
        self.listOfClasses.append(newMyClass)
```

By Changing the line:

```
mySignal = QtCore.Signal(myClass)
```

to

```
mySignal = QtCore.Signal(QtGui.QMainWindow)
```

seems to fix the error, but I am not sure if that is the correct way to do something like this, other than it probably isn't the best way to do what I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to do this would be to define the signal as

```
mySignal = QtCore.Signal(object)
```

since you wish to emit an instance of a class.

**EDIT**: If you wish to work around the circular dependency, you can place your signal in a wrapper class. E.g.

```
class myClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myClass, self).__init__(parent)
        # Note: argument of "self" is to parent the object
        self.signalwrapper = MyWrapper(self)

    def create_new_self(self):
        newSelf = myClass(self.parent())
        self.signalwrapper.mySignal.emit(newSelf)

class MyWrapper(QtCore.QObject):
    mySignal = QtCore.Signal(myClass)
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using more precise typing? So for example, if I am passing and `int` through a signal, I could also just use `object` since (nearly?) everything is "first-class"?

Comment: @busfault If you're also defining your slots using `pyqtSlot`, being more specific in your types may allow you to catch errors.  It can also be good if you're sending signals across threads, and the documentation indicates that it can be more memory efficient.

Comment: @BrendanAbel I am using `PySide` which doesn't have `pyqtSlot`, only `QtCore.Slot()` does `pyqtSlot` offer the ability to catch "type" errors? An Issue I ran into once was I changed a `Signal` definition and not the corresponding `Slot` and suddenly the `Slot` was no longer getting the `Signal`.

Comment: @busfault I am unsure of the technicalities of this, but in case it matters, I've provided an additional solution in my answern which allows you to specify the type correctly.